# Removing dash delimiter for page ranges in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I wish to change the way page numbers are displayed at the end of each glossary entry for page ranges. For example, instead of showing 16-19, I would like it to display each page in which the entry is referenced in the main body of text (i.e. 16, 17, 18, 19).

Is there some way in which this can be done?

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt] {report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=page, hyperfootnotes=false, hidelinks, colorlinks, citecolor=OliveGreen, linkcolor=Blue, linktocpage, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}
{\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 8cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.5\hsize}}}
 {\end{longtable}}
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Entry}{name={Entry}, description={This is a glossary entry. I want the page number entries to display 1, 2, 3 instead of 1--3.}}
\newglossaryentry{Entry2}{name={Entry2}, description={This is another glossary entry.}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[style=mylong]

\chapter{Introduction}
This is an \gls{Entry}. This is another \gls{Entry2}.

\newpage

This is the same entry on another page \gls{Entry}.

\newpage

This is the same entry on yet another page \gls{Entry}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. For this question it would be really helpful if you gave people a simple example of a glossary to work from. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use the [xindy](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xindy) option to the [glossaries package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) together with the `\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength` command. According to the `glossaries` manual you should be able to use

```
\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{none}
```

but this did not work for me. Instead I used

```
\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{100}
```

To create the glossary this way you need to add `xindy` as an option to the `glossaries` package and then run the `makeglossaries` command from the command line/shall, which will call `xindy` for you. With your MWE this produces

[image]

Note that the page numbers are `3,4,5`, rather than `1,2,3`, because of the title pages.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt] {report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=page, hyperfootnotes=false, hidelinks, colorlinks, citecolor=OliveGreen, linkcolor=Blue, linktocpage, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot, nogroupskip, xindy]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyMinRangeLength{100}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}
{\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 8cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.5\hsize}}}
 {\end{longtable}}
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Entry}{name={Entry}, description={This is a glossary entry. I want the page number entries to display 1, 2, 3 instead of 1--3.}}
\newglossaryentry{Entry2}{name={Entry2}, description={This is another glossary entry.}}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[style=mylong]

\chapter{Introduction}
This is an \gls{Entry}. This is another \gls{Entry2}.

\newpage

This is the same entry on another page \gls{Entry}.

\newpage

This is the same entry on yet another page \gls{Entry}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without xindy? I am currently using makeindex to create my glossary.

Comment: @SanjaySekaran Not as far as I know